# C# RichTextBox ReadOnly Event

Tags: c#, richtextbox, readonly

I have a read only rich text box and an editable text box.  The text from the read only is from the editable.  They can't be viewed at the same time. When the user presses a key it hides the read only and then selects that position in the editable.

I would like it to enter the key that was pressed into the editable without playing the error "ding"

I'm thinking that an override of the read only error function would be ideal but i'm not sure what that is.

```
    private void EditCode(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        int cursor = txtReadOnly.SelectionStart;
        tabText.SelectedIndex = 0;
        ToggleView(new object(), new EventArgs());
        txtEdit.SelectionStart = cursor;
        txtEdit.Text.Insert(cursor, e.KeyChar.ToString());
    }
```

Answer:

```
    private void EditCode(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        int cursor = txtCleanCode.SelectionStart;
        tabText.SelectedIndex = 0;
        ToggleView(new object(), new EventArgs());

        txtCode.Text = txtCode.Text.Insert(cursor, e.KeyChar.ToString());

        txtCode.SelectionStart = cursor + 1;
    }
```

I'll have to make it check if it's a non-control char but that's another deal.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: _When the user presses a key it hides the read only and then selects that position in the editable_ Now which position would that be? One the user has found with mouse and cursor keys? How do you switch back to the rtf from the editbox?

Comment: tabTxt.SelectedIndex = 0;
ToggleView(new object(), new EventArgs());

Will switch the text boxese.  This is a tab control that the user can click as well.

Comment: Ok I got it working.  The issue was the txtEdit line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to make the rich text box editable but canceling out all keys:

```
private void richtextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Stop the character from being entered into the control
    e.Handled = true;
    // add any other code here
}
```

Comment: Nice.  This got rid of the annoying "bing" when a key was pressed in the ReadOnly box.  Doesn't enter the text into the other box still but no biggie.  Thanks!

Comment: upvoted, but this does not prevent the user from deleting content

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way: Check for `<Enter>` so the user can still use the navigation keys:

```
private void txtReadOnly_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;  // no ding for normal keys in the read-only!
        txtEdit.SelectionStart = txtReadOnly.SelectionStart;
        txtEdit.SelectionLength = txtReadOnly.SelectionLength;
    }
}
```

No need to fiddle with a cursor. Make sure to have:

```
txtEdit.HideSelection = false;
```

and maybe also

```
txtReadOnly.HideSelection = false;
```

Obviously to keep the two synchronized :

```
private void txtEdit_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtReadOnly.Text = txtEdit.Text;
}
```

You will need o decide on some way fo r the user to return from editing to viewing. Escape should be reserved for aborting the edit! Maybe Control-Enter?

Comment: Just noticed you had the e.Handled too.  That got me closer but not to the finish line yet.  Thanks!

Comment: The syn'ching was so simple, I thought you had that working. Did you understand the various question I asked ;-?